# Predicting iteratively with trained classifier in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

I have trained a classifier model with 120 features, for predicting I am using this code.

```
file = open('/Users/arjun/DataSets/Cleaned_for_testing.txt').readlines()
trained_file = open(
    '/Users/arjun/Projects/Classification/trained_models/final_classifier.pkl',
    'rb')
model = pickle.load(trained_file)
for i in file:
    features = features_for_sentence(i)
    result = model.predict(features)
    print(result)
```

It is a binary classifier. When I run this, the features for the new text are generated on the fly and then fed to the model. And the output I get is

[1 1 1 1]

[1 1 1 1 1 1 1]

[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]

[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]

The results are getting appended. How to avoid this or get results one by one.

Comment: What does the `features_for_sentence` function do?

Comment: It returns the features from the text input, it will as the same sort of data that was used for training.